# Multi-Line Regex

Tags: regex, puppet

I'm trying to write a regex that can encompass a few scenarious. Mainly these:

```
node 'test1000.sov.local' {
include AV::AB
}
```

or

```
node 'test1000.sov.local' {
include ZY::ZT::ZZ
include AV::AB
}
```

or

```
node 'test1000.sov.local' {
include ZY::ZT::ZZ
include preinstall::global
include AV::AB
}
```

Theoretically it could be any number of includes under the node

This is the regex I'm attempting to use to cover this.

```
node\s'test1000.sov.local'\s{\n+.*\n+}
```

I've also tried to use

```
node\s'morpheustest1000.sov.local'\s{\n*.*\n}
```

The former doesn't really work well and the latter will only get the one include but not multiple includes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the expression supposed to form a valid manifest? Or are you looking for a regex that will be matched by a range of node definitions that exist in your manifest?

Comment: It's in the form of a valid manifest

Comment: So you expect to put this regex in site.pp? What should it do?

Comment: yes, technically in nodes.pp but same thing, it is just a simple task that will add and remove a node form the nodes.pp file

Comment: OK, misunderstanding. Note that a node name can be a *regex*. I just wanted to make sure you were not trying to overdo that. But this is fine then.

Answer (score 0):

How about this expression:

```
/((?:node 'test1000\.sov\.local' {)(?:.*)(?:}))/s
```

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sL8uX8)**

- **`/s`** will treat the string as single line. With this change change **`.*`** will match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.
- **`?:`** the none matching group is optional here but it was added to make a single group match.
- **`\.`** it is also important to scape **`.`** as they have an special meaning in Regex.